# How to handle/catch error from database trigger, in YII2

Tags: database, error-handling, triggers, yii2

this is my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_cek_pengurus
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_pengurus
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_cek NUMBER(2);
BEGIN

IF :NEW.jabatan = 1 OR :NEW.jabatan = 2 THEN

    select count(id)
    into v_cek
    from tbl_pengurus
    where idkoperasi = :NEW.idkoperasi and jabatan = :NEW.jabatan;

    IF v_cek > 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'kepengurusan sudah ada');
    END IF;

END IF;
END;
/
```

nah.., if the trigger have a return value is good,:v but it doesn't :v
so I set RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR

And this is my controller

```
public function actionTambahPengurus()
{
    $model = new Pengurus();
     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $model->IDKOPERASI = Yii::$app->user->identity->ID;
        if($model->save())
            return $this->redirect('kepengurusan');
     }

    return $this->render('tambah-pengurus',[
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

And then I get error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20000 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-20000: kepengurusan sudah ada
ORA-06512: at "DB_KOPERASI.TRG_CEK_PENGURUS", line 13
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DB_KOPERASI.TRG_CEK_PENGURUS'
(ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO "TBL_PENGURUS" ("NIK", "NAMA", "JABATAN", "EMAIL", "TGL_LAHIR", "ALAMAT", "TELEPON", "IDKOPERASI") VALUES ('2110131041', 'Rahmat Heru Kurniawan', 1, 'rahmatheruka2@gmail.com2', '3 July, 2015', 'sidoarjo', '0987654321', 8) RETURNING "ID" INTO :qp8
```

this is good, because this tell me that trigger is working
but of course this is bad for my website. 
So i want to handle this, I've tries various ways from google, but nothing works. 
Please.. is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I remember, any database related error will throw `yii\db\Exception`. You can use standard `try` / `catch` block to handle that:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (\yii\db\Exception $e) {
    ...
}
```